# Is there any way to read an Epub file while it is downloading?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, epub

I currently have an Android and iOS app that downloads and reads an epub file stored in a remote server. Currently the epub is fully downloaded before being unzipped and displayed.

Now, the client requested for a way for the user to be able to read the content of the epub while the epub is being downloaded. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you split the epub in chunks and download the first piece synchronously and the other parts asynchronously? At that point one of your api might be GET book1/chunk1/  (might be first chapter for example)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to achieve this, if you download a (zipped) EPUB file. You can "stream" if you store the EPUB in uncompressed form on your server, and provide a suitable API for retrieving its parts as said by deathyr.

BTW, the latter is what Readium cloud reader does. See https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer